# How to move scrollView down 44x to make room for NavBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, navbar

I am using the following code to create my scrollview. I would like to move the scrollView down 44px to make room for my nav bar.

```
scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scroll.delegate = self;
image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Menu.png"]];
scroll.contentSize = image.frame.size;
[scroll addSubview:image];
scroll.minimumZoomScale = scroll.frame.size.width / image.frame.size.width;
scroll.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
[scroll setZoomScale:scroll.minimumZoomScale];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

[scroll addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
self.view = scroll;
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add 44 to the UIscrollView's frame.origin.y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, to manually create a frame do:

scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,44,320,480)];

:)

This is for iPod and iphone View but this will let the scroll start at 44px

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just add a scroll view in in interface builder as an outlet, place it underneath your nav bar.

Declare scroll view in .h

in .m under ViewDidLoad

```
[scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scroll setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 1000)]; ////or whatever size you want here
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to init it with a different frame... but it depends on where/how this nav bar is being created.  If you have a view controller, and these are all subviews of the view controller's view, then you should be creating the objects in viewDidLoad, then just create the nav bar first, using self.view.bounds to obtain the initialization width.  I assume you'll want to put UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin as the autoResizingMask here.  Then if the scrollview is the rest of the view below the nav bar, you can create the frame for it using

```
CGRect scrollFrame = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 0, navbar.bounds.size.height)
```

Put an autoresizingMask of UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleHeight on the scrollview.

If you are creating the views in a different place/way, then some of that might need modification.  I was assuming your view is a nav bar at the top, x pixels tall (44 in this case but it doesn't and shouldn't matter in the context of setting the scrollview frame). and then a scrollview that fills the rest of the view.